# string - How to get the contents within first set of quotation marks and put into an array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, quotations

I want to extract the text from within the **first** set of quotes for each line and put into an array. For example, take this text:

```
2014-03-20 16:53:39.741 -0700   Information 638 NICOLE  Client "[WebDirect]" opening a connection from "24.114.54.155 (24.114.54.155)" using "iPad Safari 7.0 [fmwebdirect]".
2014-03-20 16:53:39.741 -0700   Information 94  NICOLE  Client "[WebDirect] (24.114.54.155) [24.114.54.155]" opening database "ProShopPartner_v1" as "[Guest]".
2014-03-20 16:58:45.163 -0700   Information 98  NICOLE  Client "[WebDirect] (24.114.54.155) [24.114.54.155]" closing database "ProShopPartner_v1" as "[Guest]".
2014-03-20 16:58:45.163 -0700   Information 22  NICOLE  Client "[WebDirect] (24.114.54.155) [24.114.54.155]" closing a connection.
```

The array should contain:

```
[WebDirect]
[WebDirect] (24.114.54.155) [24.114.54.155]
[WebDirect] (24.114.54.155) [24.114.54.155]
[WebDirect] (24.114.54.155) [24.114.54.155]
```

Right now I have:

```
$filename = 'C:/Program Files/FileMaker/FileMaker Server/Logs/Access2.txt';

$lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

foreach ($lines as $line) {

    $matches = array();
    preg_match('/^[^"]*"([^"]*)"$/', $lines, $matches);
    $contentInsideFirstQuotes= $matches[1];
}
```

But it won't give me only the content within the **first** set of quotes.

Comment: `/"(.*?)"/` would do just as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going line by line, just keep it simple with `"([^"]*)"` and use `preg_match()` which will do a non-global search (returning only the first match):

```
foreach($lines as $line) {
    if(preg_match('/"([^"]*)"/', $line, $matches)) {
        $result[] = $matches[1];
    }
}
```

---

If you wanted to do the entire file at once, you could use a global match (`preg_match_all()`) and prepend `.*` after the above expression.  This will match everything up until a newline character:

```
"([^"]*)".*
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/vJ4sT6)

---

Finally, to remove the capture group from the initial expression you can use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
foreach($lines as $line) {
    if(preg_match('/(?<=")[^"]*(?=")/', $line, $matches)) {
        $result[] = reset($matches); // $matches[0]
    }
}
```

---

*Notes:* I use `[^"]*` (greedy) instead of `.*?` (lazy) because it is more specific and will prevent unnecessary backtracking.  Also, if you want to require something between the quotations (i.e., `test "" "foo bar"` returning `foo bar` not ) then change the `*` to `+`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $filename = 'C:/Program Files/FileMaker/FileMaker Server/Logs/Access2.txt';

    $lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $result = array();
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        preg_match('/^[^"]*"([^"]*)"$/', $line, $matches);
        $result[] = $matches[1];
    }

print_r($result);
```